# Importar projetos netbeans do Github no Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Meu professor tem um um github pra onde envia todo material produzido em sala, porém, ele usa o netbeans...Gostaria de saber se consigo importar esses projetos no Eclipse? Uso o EGit no Eclipse.

Comment: Olá consegue sim, que tecnologia é o projeto? java-se ou Java-EE

Comment: A primeira, como proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa amigo, tudo bom?

Já tive esse problema também e não me orgulho muito da maneira que eu resolvi, mas lá vai:

Existem alguns arquivos chatos de cada IDE que você usa que ficam junto ao seu projeto.

Vi alguns tutoriais pelo Google e não achei nada muito clean pra fazer. O que eu fiz, como era um projeto simples da faculdade, foi criar um novo projeto Java no eclipse, copiar todas as libs que eu necessitava e copiar todas as classes e arquivos de configuração do meu projeto que estava no netbeans para o projeto eclipse.

Evitei copiar arquivos de configuração da IDE, o processo não demorou muito e em pouco tempo estava com o projeto rodando no eclipse. Acredito que essa é uma maneira limpa de fazer isso, porém nada automatizada.

Espero ter ajudado.